# How to exit case statement as soon as my condition becomes true in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I am using case statement in postgresql and have 4 "when" conditions, I would like to have as soon as the condition becomes true it should exit the case statement. Suppose i have 4 "when" conditions and when case runs if first statement is true then do not excite the remaining 3 conditions.

Also suppose if first condition is false then it goes to next and if next is true then exit.

[image]

The above image is like my config table from where i have to pick col6 values if its matching with my other tables.

For example col1, col2, col3 are mandatory to match but for col4 and col5 are optional. So from my actual data set if col1,col2 and col3 matches then i have to check if col5 and col4 are also matching giving first preference to col5.

Suppose col1, col2, col3 are matching and then if only col5 matches but on col4 then accordinly i have to take value from. Also col1, col2, col3 are matching and both col5 and  col4 are matching then accordingly i have to take values.

If col1, col2, col3 are matching with my main data set and col4 and col5 are not matching then accordingly i have to take value from col6.

Hope i am clear and for this i am writing the case statement

Comment: Please illustrate issue with data. SQL's `CASE` should process as you intend. Per Postgres' [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html): *If the condition's result is true, the value of the CASE expression is the result that follows the condition, and the remainder of the CASE expression is not processed.*

Comment: Added the complete description in the main question. Thanks

Comment: @abc . . . What you describe is *exactly* how `cased` **expressions** work.  And O. Jones has already pointed that out.

Comment: Yes but this case will run on all rows, but i want to have if one of my case statement is true on any one row then it should exit and not check the other condition for other rows....

Comment: Suppose my first case statement is true for the first row in my above data set then I should get the result as 4 and the case should stop executing for other rows.

Answer (score 1):

`CASE WHEN ... THEN` already does what you describe.  When an early condition is matched, later ones aren't evaluated.

**Edit** According to comments you want the CASE / WHEN / THEN rules to change partway through the query.  But, that's not the way SQL works: it's a [declarative language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_paradigms), not an imperative language. You tell SQL what you want, not how to get it.

SQL query engines process rows in an *unpredictable* order. They may even process multiple rows in parallel.  So, with respect, the very concept of changing the query *after* it encounters a condition in a certain row makes no sense, because *after* makes no sense in SQL's world.

You may be able to use LEFT JOINs to get what you want. Something like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       a.col1, a.col2, a.col3,
       CASE
       WHEN b.col4 = a.col4 AND c.col5 = a.col5 THEN b.col4
       WHEN d.col6 = a.col6 THEN d.col6
       ELSE '???' END matched
  FROM tablea a
  LEFT JOIN tableb b ON a.col4 = b.col4
  LEFT JOIN tablec c ON a.col5 = c.col5
  LEFT JOIN tabled d ON a.col6 = d.col6
```

Comment: Added the complete description in the main question. Thanks

Comment: Yes but this case will run on all rows, but i want to have if one of my case statement is true on any one row then it should exit and not check the other condition for other rows....

Comment: Suppose my first case statement is true for the first row in my above data set then I should get the result as 4 and the case should stop executing for other rows.